# Not able to show external image links in spotify

Tags: spotify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook profile images in spotify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327035/facebook-profile-images-in-spotify)

External image url not working on spotify , for example the image mentioned below:

```
<img src=http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/488121_10151271660139574_1555853574_s.jpg />
```

I need to show a lot of images from external links , please help me to get this.

Comment: You should pass `image source url` in `" "`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you add all addresses you need for external images to RequiredPermissions. https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/integration/#permissions